# iOS App craches on UIActionSheet

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiactionsheet

I have an UITableview. When a row is selected an UIActionSheet pops up. To add the UIActionSheet I used

```
[actionSheet showFromRect:cell.bounds inView:cell animated:NO];
```

Everything works fine, i can select items in the UIActionView, i can tap outside and it disappears. BUT when it disappears (from tapping outside or selecting an item) and i tap fast on something else, e.g. the background, the app crashes with following message:

```
-[UIActionSheet _dismissForTappedIndex:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x173796d0
```

I guess the app weants to dismiss the sheet, but it has been released before? Thank you for any help.

Comment: Are you building for iOS8, using Xcode 6? What delegate method are you calling? Are you using clickedButtonAtIndex method for example?

Comment: Yes I am. I tried **willDismissWithButtonIndex** and **didDismissWithButtonIndex**, without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to keep a reference to the UIActionSheet. Make it a property for example. This error means that ARC is deallocating the object too fast.IF the error stops happening then thats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the 'clickedButtonAtIndex' delegate method to catch the tap, under iOS8 I experienced crashing too, though it was fixed when changed to didDismissButtonAtIndex.

I had a similar crash with UIAlertView so this may also be the case with UIActionSheet.

Under iOS8, please change your delegate method `clickedButtonAtIndex` to **`didDismissWithButtonIndex`**

change this line to

```
 - (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
```

with this

```
 - (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet willDismissWithButtonIndex (NSInteger)buttonIndex {
```

You should find this will solve the crash.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The question is about `UIActionSheet`, not `UIAlertView`.

Comment: @rmaddy Sorry, my mistake, read too quickly. I'll check this and update answer

Comment: Thank you but neither **willDismissWithButtonIndex** nor **didDismissWithButtonIndex** are successful :-(.